# Minimizing vector or function by keeping one variable constrained

Tags: matlab, math, optimization

I have to minimize the e f g and h by varying n within a bound between 0 to 1 and k without boundation.

```
% Data is as follows
x = [  1.4   15.15    49.395    98.8  151.475    184.41    230.51    259.2 ];
y = [ 12.15  21.2125  25.15125  25.3   24.63125   28.8975   29.8725   35.2 ];

% create model function q with parameters p(1) = k and p(2) = n
    q = @(p, x) p(1)*x.^(-p(2));

%create the desired error-functions for minimization
e = @(p) sum((y.^2 - q(p, x)).^2); %// minimization function
f = @(p) sum(abs(y - q(p, x))); %// better sum over absolute values
g = @(p) sum(sqrt(abs(q(p, x) - y))); %// better take square roots of absolute values
h = @(p) sum((q(p, x) - y).^2); %// default minimizaton function

p0 = [1, -0.5]; % an initial guess 

[p_fit_e, r_e] = fminsearch(e, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_f, r_f] = fminsearch(f, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_g, r_g] = fminsearch(g, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_h, r_h] = fminsearch(h, p0) % Optimize
```

% afterwards I have another set of data of x and y and to do the same as above

```
 x = [  1.6   17.17    46.54    96.68  147.743    181.67    237.51    251.2 ];
 y = [ 11.13  21.22  27.15125  33.3   36.125   43.5689   56.25   65.12 ];
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Zéychin  I have multiple sets of x and y. One of them is as follows:

x = [  1.4   15.15    49.395    98.8  151.475    184.41    230.51    259.2 ]
y = [ 12.15  21.2125  25.15125  25.3   24.63125   28.8975   29.8725   35.2 ]

In addition to that, I have two parameters k and n which are related to x as follows

q = k.* x^-n

I have functions:

e = q.*q - y.*y

f = q-y

g = (q-y)^1/2  and h

First I want to minimize function e related to y as follows:

e = q.*q - y.*y  by keeping  n between 0 to 1 

Afterwards I want to simultaneously minimize function f, followed by g.

Comment: @Zéychin   afterwards i want to do it with  another set of character   x= [ 1.6 17.17 46.54 96.68 147.743 181.67 237.51 251.2 ]; y = [ 11.13 21.22 27.15125 33.3 36.125 43.5689 56.25 65.12 ]